# variable is used before its initialization

Tags: angular

i want to initally assign updateName to shipment object name property but it is giving the error Property 'shipment' is used before its initialization.

```
export class ShipmentInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  shipment: any;
  updateName = this.shipment.name;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
    private shipmentService: ShipmentService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getShipment();
  }
  getShipment(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.shipmentService.getShipment(id).subscribe((shipment) => {
      this.shipment = shipment;
    });
  }
  toUpdateName(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (this.updateName !== '') {
      this.shipmentService
        .updateName(id, this.updateName)
        .subscribe((shipment) => {
          this.shipment = shipment;
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: well you do not have the shipment before you service has returned the name, is there a special reason why you need that name early, else you could set a dummy on shipment. If it has to come same time you will have to set the updatename insde your get shipment, then its possible

Comment: The variable `shipment` is obviously undefined in the statement `updateName = this.shipment.name;`. You either need to initialize the `shipment`: `shipment = { name: 'sample' }` (inelegant IMO) or provide other value to `updateName`: `updateName = ''` or leave it undefined: `updateName: any;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your `updateName = this.shipment.name;` into constructor initialization.

Answer (score 0):

@Sambhav, you're write

```
updateName = this.shipment.name;
```

This only "change" the variable "updateName" when the instruction is executed, **not** create a relation between the shipment object and the variable, **not** change when this.shipment object change. You can use a getter -it's a confortable way to has a "function", really you has no a new variable

```
get updateName(){
    return this.shipment?this.shipment.name:null
}
```

Or, each time you change this.shipment, change the variable,e.g. when you subscribe to getShipment

```
this.shipmentService.getShipment(id).subscribe((shipment) => {
      this.shipment = shipment;
      this.updateName=this.shipment.name
    });
```

BTW: if you need use in yout html you needn't create a getter or a new variable, you can use the "safe operator" (yes the `?.`)

```
name: {{shipment?.name}}
```

And yes, the problem is that when you equal the variable this.shipment has no value